# How can I avoid a "too big sqrt" when using underbrace

Tags: underbrace, sqrt

Code Sample:

```
\sqrt{\underbrace{\det((D\varphi)^T)}_{\det(D\varphi)} \det(D\varphi)}
```

Produces:

[image]

The problem: By using the underbrace, it is set **in** the square root and not **under** the square root - so the square root is bigger than the line height. How can I avoid this?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I've retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proposed solution uses a command `\ubrace` that better than `\underbrace` because it makes an ordinary atom instead of an operator atom and has a more conforming LaTeX syntax.

The argument to `\usqrt` is saved in a box where `\ubrace` is redefined to only deliver its first argument. So we can use this box as a phantom in order to set the radical to the desired height and width.

We back up by the width of this box and retypeset the argument with the normal meaning of `\ubrace`.

In the picture, the second formula is meant to provide a check for everything going as expected.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}
\newsavebox{\usqrtbox}
\newcommand{\usqrt}[1]{% square root with underbraced material
  \sbox{\usqrtbox}{%
    \renewcommand{\ubrace}[2]{##1}% deliver only the main part
    $\displaystyle#1$%
  }%
  \sqrt{\phantom{\usebox{\usqrtbox}}}\hspace*{-\wd\usqrtbox}#1%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\usqrt{
  \ubrace{\det((D\varphi)^T)}{\det(D\varphi)}
  \det(D\varphi)
}=x
\]
\[
\sqrt{\det((D\varphi)^T)\det(D\varphi)}=x
\]

\end{document}
```

There is a small difference: indeed, TeX uses the cramped `\displaystyle` inside a square root. You can fix this by using `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\ubrace}[2]{{\underbrace{\ifsqrt\expandafter\cramped\fi{#1}}_{#2}}}

\newif\ifsqrt
\newsavebox{\usqrtbox}
\newcommand{\usqrt}[1]{% square root with underbraced material
  \begingroup
  \sqrttrue
  \sbox{\usqrtbox}{%
    \renewcommand{\ubrace}[2]{\cramped{##1}}% deliver only the main part
    $\displaystyle#1$%
  }%
  \sqrt{\phantom{\usebox{\usqrtbox}}}\hspace*{-\wd\usqrtbox}%
  #1%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\[
\usqrt{
  \ubrace{\det((D\varphi)^T)}{\det(D\varphi)}
  \det(D\varphi)
}=x
\]
\[
\sqrt{\det((D\varphi)^T)\det(D\varphi)}=x
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]